# Django form with object list

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a problem to get back an object from a django form after submission.

I have an object list (filled with `MyObject`, not a django model) filled by another python package.

In `models.py`, I have :

```
class MyObjectForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get the list
        myobjects = kwargs.pop('myobjects')
        super(MyObjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = [(o, o.name) for o in myobjects]
        self.fields["my_objects"] = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

For information, the HTML looks OK.

In `views.py`, `form.is_valid()` is always `False` when I click on the submit button. Is there a problem ?

When I change models.py with :

```
self.fields["my_objects"] = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=choices, required=False)
```

In `views.py`, `form.is_valid()` is `True` but I can't get back my objet `MyObject` (I get an empty value). Is that possible ? And if yes, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what you used as choices... `MyObject` instances, really ? How is a `MyObject` instance supposed to be sent to a browser as part of a HTML form and then back to your server thru a POST request body ?

If you have some persistant unique identifier for each of your `MyObject` instances, use this for your choices, ie

```
choices = [(o.some_stable_and_unique_id, o.name) for o in myobjects]
```

Note that it won't solve all of your issues... You'll then have to subclass `TypedChoiceField` to retrieve the object based on its "id" etc.

Comment: `MyObject` is an oject with some properties created by another package (which not intended to be save in database).
I thought it was impossible...

I don't have a unique identifier but I can create one and a dictionary in `views.py` before passing the list in form constructor and retrieve the selected object after form validation with this custom ID. Thanks.